# Martingale theorem representation using two martingales

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Suposse we have two martingales $N$ and $M$, and the hypothesis of martingale representation theorem holds. Then
\begin{equation}
N_t=\int_0^t\psi_sdW_s, \,\, M_t=\int_0^t\phi_sdW_s
\end{equation}
So, my question is there a result that guarantees that is possible to have
\begin{equation}
N_t=\int_0^t\psi_sdW_s=\int_0^t\frac{\psi_s}{\phi_s}\phi_sdW_s=\int_0^t\frac{\psi_s}{\phi_s}dM_s
\end{equation}

For example is possible when  $\mathbb{P}(M_t>0)=1$ for all $t\in[0,T]$. Any suggestion or advice is welcome. Thank you!.

Comment: This is obviously possible when $\phi_s>0.$